# Map ternary relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

im try to map a ternary relationship. The ER Model is the next:
[image]

Responsable is an user, Alumno is another type of user (a student). And TipoRelacion define if Responsable is mother, father or tutor of the student (Alumno).

So, i think, map the relationship (alumno_relacion_responsable) and define bidireccionals OneToMany from other tables.

My entities are:

```
class Responsable{
     // other declarations

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ResponsableAlumno", mappedBy="alumno")
     */
    protected $hijos;

    // More declarations
}

class Alumno{
     // other declarations

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ResponsableAlumno", mappedBy="responsable")
     */
    protected $padres;

    // More declarations
}
```

So, in the relationchip entity:

```
Class ResponsableAlumno{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="Responsable_IdUsuario")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Responsable", inversedBy="idusuario")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Responsable_IdUsuario", referencedColumnName="idusuario")
     */

    protected $responsable;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="Alumno_IdUsuario")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Alumno", inversedBy="idusuario")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Alumno_IdUsuario", referencedColumnName="idusuario")
     */
    protected $alumno;

    // Other declarations
}
```

But, when test the entities, Symfony says (on load script):

> Notice: Undefined index: alumno in
>   /var/www/AppsManantiales/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php

Any ideas about what is my error ?.

Answer (score 1):

The inversedBy setting should match the "hijos" and "padres" not the ID of the associated entity. There are a couple other problems, ORM\Id should not be specified on the relational columns, and the Column also need not be specified:

```
class ResponsableAlumno{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Responsable", inversedBy="hijos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Responsable_IdUsuario", referencedColumnName="idusuario")
     */

    protected $responsable;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Alumno", inversedBy="padres")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Alumno_IdUsuario", referencedColumnName="idusuario")
     */
    protected $alumno;

    // Other declarations
}
```

Though, I do believe you have the relations flipped, I imagine you are looking for something more like this:

- Many Responsable to One ResponsableAlumno
- Many Alumno to One ResponsableAlumno
- One ResponsableAlumno to Many Responsable
- One ResponsableAlumno to Many Alumno

Or more likely One Alumno to One ResponsableAlumno and vice versa.

Check here for full documentation on the relationship syntax and settings for Doctrine:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/association-mapping.html